# Tab delimited text file to array in javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have a text file that has multiple data with a format:

```
1 2016-01-01 17:23:24 0 0 1 1
2 2016-02-01 07:15:23 0 0 2 1
1 2016-03-01 12:13:24 0 0 1 1
3 2016-04-02 13:34:19 0 0 3 1
.....
```

Code:

```
<table>
<tr>
  <td colspan="2" style="font-weight:bold;">
    Upload time sheet for yards with biometrics
  </td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td colspan="2" style="font-weight:bold;">
    <input type="file" name="fileUpload" id="fileUpload" size="40">
  </td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td colspan="2" >
    &nbsp;
  </td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <th>Date From:</th><th>Date To:</th>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td><input type="date" id="from_date"></td><td><input type="date" id="to_date"></td>
</tr>
  <td colspan="2" align="right">
    <input type="button" value="Process File" id="btn_process_file" onclick="Upload()">
  </td>
</table>
```

I need to get certain values on each line of the file to be placed in an array. I only need the first 3 "values" for each line in an array. Based on my sample above, I just need:

```
1 2016-01-01 17:23:24
2 2016-02-01 07:15:23
1 2016-03-01 12:13:24
```

To make array like:

```
var x = [[1,2016-01-01,17:23:24][2,2016-02-01,07:15:23][1,2016-03-01,12:13:24]]
```

Comment: `var x = [[1,2016-01-01,17:23:24][2,2016-02-01,07:15:23][1,2016-03-01,12:13:24]]
` isn't even valid JS. Please improve the question

Answer (score 1):

You can use it like this.

```
     $.get('file://your path', function(allText ) {
   var result = allText.split("\t");
  //and access them with index value like this
   alert(result.1);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You could also use a input file for files like  `<input type="file" accept='text/plain' onchange='readText(this)'/>`

so you can get the content of a chosen file by using a file reader:

```
function readText(filePath) {
        var output = ""; 
        if(filePath.files && filePath.files[0]) {           
            reader.onload = function (e) {
                output = e.target.result;
                displayContents(output);
            };
            reader.readAsText(filePath.files[0]);
            var result = output.split("\t");
            console.log(result);
        }
}


var result = output.split("\t");
```

splitts your string to an array. Divided by tabs.

You can also create a GET-Request on a File on your system.

If you dont use jquery, take this:

```
var file = "file://your path"
var toread= new XMLHttpRequest();
toread.open("GET", file, false);
toread.onreadystatechange = function ()
{
    if(toread.readyState === 4)
    {
        if(toread.status === 200 || toread.status == 0)
        {
            var allText = toread.responseText;
        }
    }
}
toread.send(null);
var result = allText.split("\\n");
```

using jquery would make it a bit easier:

```
$.get('file://your path', function(allText ) {
   var result = (allText.split("\\n");
}, 'text')
```

Comment: Thanks for the lesson but I can get the file fine. My problem is on reading the file and placing certain columns only into an array.

Comment: give me a second i'll add it to the awnser

Answer (score -1):

```
function Upload(){
    var files = document.getElementById('fileUpload').files;

    if(files.length){
        var file = files[0]; // first
        var reader = new FileReader();
        reader.onload = onReadFile;
        reader.onerror = onError;
        reader.readAsText(file);
    }
}

function onReadFile(file){
    var txt = file.target.result;
    var list = txt.split('\n');
    var result = list.map(function(item){
        return item.split(' ');
    });

    console.log(result);
}


function onError (){
    //**//
}
```